# prune_strategy don't work in capybara-screenshot, folder with screenshots is not automatic cleared

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

On our application we use RSpec, Capybara and Capybara-screenshot. All things work fine except cleaning `tmp/screenshots` folder. The project is configured with default settings, so images are saved in the screenshots folder. New screenshots with failed tests are added to the old ones and are difficult to find and identify problems in tests.

Capybara-screenshot has default method `prune_strategy` to do this, but it didn't work.

After implement a new function, we need to fix/create a test, and then manually empty the folder with screenshots and only then run tests so as not to confuse the old screenshots and the new ones. Is there a way to configure this folder to be automatically cleaned up after running the `rspec` command, but before running the tests?

```rb
# Gemfile

ruby '2.6.6'
gem 'rails', '5.2.0'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end
```

```rb
# spec/rails_helper.rb

require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)
abort('The Rails environment is running in production mode!') if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
require 'rspec/rails'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara-screenshot/rspec'

Capybara.asset_host = 'http://localhost:5000'
Capybara::Screenshot.prune_strategy = :keep_last_run

# Also tried with this config:
# Capybara::Screenshot.prune_strategy = { keep: 20 }
```

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1):

From the capybara-screenshot gem

```
def wildcard_path
  File.expand_path('*.{html,png}', Screenshot.capybara_root)
end

def prune_with_last_run_strategy
  FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir.glob(wildcard_path))
end
```

So it will remove all html and png files from the Screenshot.capybara_root directory - Obviously that wouldn't work if you're not screenshotting in png or html and if you're changing the directory after pruning has occurred.

Note, that from the code it looks like pruning is only done when the screenshot is saved, so if you have no failures in your run it wouldn't actually prune the screenshots from the previous run.  If that's not the behavior you want it looks like you should be able to add an RSpec `before(:suite)` block that calls `Capybara::Screenshot.prune`